# Jquery cancelar solicitação ajax

Tags: jquery, request

Como posso `cancelar uma solicitação do Ajax` que ainda não recebeu a resposta usando Jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [abort()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method), exemplo:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pagina.php",
    success: function(msg){
      ...
    }
});

//aborta o request
xhr.abort();
```